# Java game engine, writing own scripting language?

Tags: java, scripting

I'm planning to create a simple Visual Novel game engine out of Java. I've developed for Java before but I have experience with other languages. What I would like to do, is to create my own scripting language that people can use with the engine to make the complete game out of a script, since Visual Novels are simple enough to do it, I think.

What I don't know is, is Java suitable for making such a scripting language? The way I imagine it is, the engine reads a script file in the game folder, and takes in the input and executes each command linking up to a certain function or something like that. I'm not sure how difficult theoretically that would be to pull off.

As you can probably tell I'm a newbie when it comes to this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a domain-specific-language (DSL). Here's an article on [DSLs within Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-dsls-in-java-1.html)

> DSLs are small, expressive programming languages custom designed for
>   specific tasks. In this four-part series, Venkat Subramaniam
>   introduces the concept of DSLs and eventually shows you how to build
>   them using Java

and there's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305729/first-steps-with-dsl-on-java) on SO.

You can use [Scala to write DSLs](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1403) and run them on the JVM. However I would warn you that without Scala knowledge it's a (IMO) non-trivial task to do this.

Alternatively you can use a Java implementation of a scripting language together with the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html). This will allow you to use an existing language and have it compiled into bytecode. The advantag eis that you're using an existing language. The disadvantage is that it's not specific to your particular needs.

Comment: At first glance, that seems to be what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't do it. Writing a new language is surprisingly complex. Designing grammar, parsing, error reporting, performance.
2. It's already there: [Creating meta language with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575085)
3. Consider [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy), [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) or [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby) first. People will love you for using familiar syntax.

Comment: Hmm, I see. The syntax I would make is very simple like being able to load a background, a character sprite and stuff like that. I should probably give it more thought as to wether my own language is a good idea, then.

Answer (score 0):

While it's technically *possible* to do this, I don't know if Java would be your best bet.  While I don't know the scope or purpose of your project, I'd recommend [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) as a game/scripting language.  (You said that you have experience with other languages, so I assume that switching to Python is ok)

Comment: Yes, this was my first consideration, but the target for this is Mac, PC and Android devices, hence why I chose Java. Didn't look into PyGame running on Android though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answers give nice directions. 
I would like to offer some more ideas: 
A. Provide a java "GAME API", which can be exposed via REST/SOAP web services and can have  
 client classes generated from (for example, take a WSDL, and generate client classes from it). 
B. Provide the API as a jar file, and have you game implement a File class loader that will load external jars, and use the classes developers will develop using the API. 
[Here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/file-class-loader/) is an example of how to implement such a class loader. 
C. Use the ScriptEngine provided by java, to invoke scripts. 
See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/RunningScriptswithJavaScriptEngine.htm) an example of how to invoke a JavaScript script from within java.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and i am a bit late for the party (though this question is not answered yet), but it is possible. From what i understand, this sounds like a job for [Just Another Framework](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/Just-Another-Framework). Full disclosure: I am the developer of the Framework i am describing. I had a similar problem and wrote this framework to reuse this system, which worked for this kind of issue.

#### TL;DR

Do not use JAF, if you want your own, fully functional, perfect language.
Use JAF, if you just want to create a simple scripting part, that decouples parts of your code or if you want to evaluate "user input" scripts at Runtime (like in the topic of this question).

> What I don't know is, is Java suitable for making such a scripting language?

You can do it with nearly every programming language. You should consider to use Javascript or Lua or [...] and put those into a file instead of creating a custom scripting language. [Java has a place for those languages](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/languages-137862.html). You should also consider to maybe read .java or .class files from a folder and take those into your "Game-Engine". If you however want to provide ***your own*** language and **no one** can change your mind about it (that was *my* issue), **JAF** can help you with that.

**JAF** is a framework, which allows you to define custom scripting languages within Java, that may be evaluated and executed at Runtime. You give the Parser some Functions, Rules as well as the raw script and the result is a fixed set of instructions (in the form of consumers), that can be executed as many times as you like.

This is by no means another language build on top of java! It is meant to be a foundation for your language. It is only meant for creating small parts though. An example would be some sort of logic that should be interchangeable without stopping the application. This logic should be executed via small scripts and provided via a Database or (like in your case) from files located in a folder.

You can use a Parser, to parse "raw-scripts" that are created by the users. This parser takes Functions and Rules in the form of a Strategy-/Command-Pattern, which basically define your language. After parsing, a "Script"-Object is returned, that can be executed as many times as you want. You can also set values of the Script and therefor connect this Script to your real and running java-code.

The real thing i loved about this however is, that you can provide custom script elements through Rules and Functions, which basically directly connect to java. Just an example would be the printline function. This calls System.out.println();. As i said, just an example, but you can imagine that you can call any existing code from your Functions and Rules.

A (very) simple example of how to use this would look like this:

```
String rawScript = ... //your users script here

Parser parser = Parser.create(); // used to parse the script
parser.add(IOModule.getPackage()); // add packages of Functions and Rules

Script script;
try {
    script = parser.parse(rawScript); // Create the Script
}  catch (ParsingFailedException e) {
    // Handle an error while parsing the script
    // Do not continue, there is no script!
}

script.setValue("yourKey", /* Whatever should be available in your script */); // Inject outside variables for your Rules/Functions

try {
    script.run(); // Execute the script
} catch (ExecutionFailedException e) {
    // Handle an error at the scripts execution
}
```

I do not want to write a book about how to use this framework. Take a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/Just-Another-Framework/wiki), it is better explained there.

The advantage of this is, that you can simply define your own language, by providing simple commands that parse specific pieces of the raw script. They are just "applied"; All the magic is hidden within the framework. It's explained a bit within the [frameworks-wiki](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/Just-Another-Framework/wiki/Script-World#functions), but i am bad at explaining. So you can create your own little scripting language by providing the building-blocks of your language without requiring deeper knowledge of theoretical computer science.

It has some issues though. It is currently not compatibly with the [JSR 223](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223). Also, it is (of course) slower than playn java.